# Create many SVG `<use>` elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'd like to have a loop that creates many identical visual elements within an `<svg>`. I plan to use `<use>` to facilitate the replication of identical elements.

JavaScript successfully adds `<use>` elements, but for some reason they are **not visible**.

Interestingly, if I save the webpage from the browser and open the saved copy, the added elements become visible. Maybe calling some kind of refresh function is necessary?

```js
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x += 30) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 100; y += 30) {
        var use = document.createElement('use');
        use.setAttribute('x', x);
        use.setAttribute('y', y);
        use.setAttribute('href', '#cube');
        use.setAttribute('onclick', 'foo()');
        document.getElementById('mysvg').appendChild(use);
    }
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg">
  <defs>
  <g id="cube">
    <rect width="21" height="24"/>
  </g>
  </defs>
    <use href="#cube" x="121" y="12"/>
    <use href="#cube" x="100" y="24"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
```

instead of

```
var use = document.createElement('use');
```

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61236874/5231110).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer